# get collection class names from common class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, classname

I want the collection array with 'info', '321' and 'danger' in jquery/Javascript. I'm having following HTML code.

And I have to use '.etape' classname for this.

```
<input class="etape btn-info others">
<input class="etape btn-321 ">
<input class="etape btn-danger others1">
<input class="etape others">
```

My worst script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myClass;
     var classNames = $('.etape').attr('class').split(/\s+/);  
     $( ".cc" ).each( function(index, item) {
        if(item.indexOf("btn-") == 0){
          myClass[] = item;
        }
     });
});
</script>
```

Please help me.

Comment: Would you share the results you are expecting?... I mean what does the array look like exactly?

Comment: You forgot to post your javascript code.

Comment: Post full source code pls.

Comment: `myClass[] = item;` is not valid

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to get `["info", "321", "danger"]` from the posted markup

```
var classes = $('.etape').map(function() {
    var m = this.className.match(/btn\-(.*?)(?:\s|$)/);
    return m ? m.pop().split('-').pop() : m;
}).get().filter(Boolean);
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/nt2qerp4/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var collection = [];
var classRegex = /btn-.*\s/;
$(".etape").each(function(index,element) {
  var className = $(element).attr('class').match(classRegex);
  if(className != null){
    var data =  className[0].replace("btn-","").trim();
    collection.push(data);
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS attr selectors:

```
$('[class*="btn-"]').val('hello');
// returns: [<input class=​"etape btn-info others">​, <input class=​"etape btn-321">​, <input class=​"etape btn-danger others1">​]
```

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tianes/dx91guLw/